# Open app with map zoomed in current location

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to create my map so that it opens to the user's current location zoomed in. However I'm having trouble doing this. I've seen several people using `getLastKnownLocation()` however this always returns `null` for me and I always get `NullPointerException`. The code I have is

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WeatherMapActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

private GoogleMap map;
private Location location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.weather_maps_main);

    initializeMap();
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coordinate));
}

private void initializeMap() {
    // check if map is created
    if(map == null) {

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); // creates the map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // enables gps to track my location
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); // enables the "return to my location" button on map
        map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true); // enables the compass button on map

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (map == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Map could not be created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initializeMap();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    map.clear();
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    marker.title("Current location");   
    map.addMarker(marker);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

I've tried putting `map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16));` in `onLocationChanged(Location location)` but this zooms in to my current location every so often when I'm trying to look at the other parts of the map.

So how do I set it so that when I open the app, it opens to the current location zoomed in and doesn't zoom in any other time?

Comment: getLastKnownLocarion returns null until the GPS or network provides a location. You will know when this happens because the callback onLocationChanged runs.

Comment: how do I get my current location as soon as I start up the map then? I see the blue dot showing my location but I don't know how to zoom in on that location.

Comment: You don't, you wait until you get a fix from the GPS or network.

Comment: How is it showing my location with `setMyLocationEnabled` if it needs a fix from the GPS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CameraPosition to do this.

```
      LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
                if (location != null)
                {
                   //here where the camera animate and zoom to particular location.
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 14));

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                    .zoom(18)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                }
```